# ArgoCD SSO Github: failed to query provider

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

I followed these instructions
https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/user-management/#dex

However getting an error of

> Failed to query provider "argo.example.net/api/dex": 400 Bad Request: 400 Bad Request

or sometimes

> 404 not found

This the code I have

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: argocd-cm
  namespace: argocd
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-cm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
data:
  url: https://argo.example.net
  dex.config: |
    connectors:
      - type: github
        id: github
        name: Github
        config:
          clientID: ${clientID}
          clientSecret: ${clientSecret}
          hostName: github.example.net
          orgs:
          - name: example
```

Comment: Any logs in the argocd-server Pod(s)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @dev1993
Are you able to figure it out this, I'm also facing same issue